# gem command not found through git bash

Tags: ruby, git, bash, github, git-bash

I'm new to git and I've been setting up a jekyll blog through my github account. I'm using the git bash command line. In the instructions one of the commands is:

```
$ gem install jekyll
```

When I run this it tells me:

```
sh.exe": gem: command not found
```

Anyone know how I can fix this? Does this have anything to do with Ruby?

Comment: Are you sure your path was configured correctly (so that the executable for gem can be found). do you know where your gem is installed? for instance on my machine: `/home/michael/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/gem` is the path to my gem and my $PATH includes `/home/michael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin`

Answer (score 3):

`gem`, [RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/), is a package manager for Ruby. It seems that it is not installed on your computer, or not available inside your $PATH.

First, try to execute `which gem` to see whether you can access it or not. Then,

- If you previously installed `gem`, you probably have to modify `$PATH` to add the package manager's executable location.
- If you did not, you need to. On Windows, your best option is to install Cygwin.

Comment: Should I be able to do it through the GitBash? When I extract the installer there and try to run it withe "ruby setup.rb" it tells me it cannot find the command "ruby". If I install it in Cygwin will I be able to use Ruby through GitBash?

Comment: A Ruby package is available in Cygwin. You could install ruby this way and then use Git via Cygwin, or locate where ruby was installed and add this location to your $PATH in GitBash to keep using Git there.